# How do I make the carousel indicators in angular ui use thumbnails from a model in a controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the angular ui bootstrap carousel and I want to make the indicators thumbnails. I have a controller that looks like this (from the demo):

```
function carouselCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myInterval = 5000;
  $scope.imgPath="img/slideshow/"
  var slides = $scope.slides = [{
    'imgName':'iguanas.jpg',
    'caption':'Marine iguanas in the Galapagos National Park on Santa Cruz Island, on September 15, 2008.',
    'author':'(Reuters/Guillermo Granja)'
  },{
    'imgName':'eruption.jpg',
    'caption':'In June of 2009, the Cerro Azul volcano on Isabela Island was in an active phase, spewing molten lava into the air, spilling it across its flanks, and widening existing lava flows.',
    'author':'(Reuters/Parque Nacional Galapagos)'
  },{
    'imgName':'bluefoot.jpg',
    'caption':'A close-up of a pair of Booby feet, photographed in March of 2008. ',
    'author':'(CC BY Michael McCullough)'
  }];

}
```

and the template looks like this:

```
<div ng-mouseenter="pause()" ng-mouseleave="play()" class="carousel">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators" ng-show="slides().length > 1">
        <li ng-repeat="slide in slides()" class="slide-thumb" ng-class="{active: isActive(slide)}" ng-click="select(slide)"></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner" ng-transclude></div>
    <a ng-click="prev()" class="carousel-control left" ng-show="slides().length > 1">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a ng-click="next()" class="carousel-control right" ng-show="slides().length > 1">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="slide in slides()" class="slide-thumb" ng-class="{active: isActive(slide)}" ng-click="select(slide)" style="background-image:url({{slide.imgName}});"></li>
```

but I must be out of scope or something... Does anyone know any angular carousels that have a thumbnail option or how I can get this to work?

Comment: where are you putting the thumb repeater? Create a demo in plunker or jsfiddle

Comment: @charlietfl the thumb repeater was in the bootstrap template, i think that's why it was out of scope..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slide array in the carousel template actually don't refer to the slides array you have defined in your app controller.

In the carousel template slides refer to a bunch of dom elements enhanced with internal properties. That's why any access to properties you have defined in our objects will failed when executed (scope issue as you guessed already).

If you want to stick to the carousel from angular-ui I would recommend a slightly different approach and go for css styling something like that:

```
  //Default styles for indicator elements
  .carousel-indicators li { 
    background-size : 42px 22px; 
    width : 42px;
    height: 22px;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-position : center;
    cursor : pointer;
  }

  // Then Specify a background image for every slide
  .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1){
    background-image: url(http://cache.wallpaperdownloader.com/bing/img/WeddedRocks_20100418.jpg);
  }

  ...
```

You can see a working Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/S4RZIIV9DCnD6mJ4ex1f?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense. I ended up not using the template for my thumbnails and did something similar to the demo, http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview , so it stays in scope. I just hide the carousel template and use the repeater thats in the scope for my thumbnails. Still not totally sure how that works but it works at least! thanks!

Comment: This can't be a solution to the problem at all. Not even a workaround. What if all the data comes from a database and it's subject to modification.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible and it's very simple. First you must pass the model of every slide in the **actual** directive as indicated in the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel) for the **uib-slide settings**. And then you must override the template using the **template-url** directive. Don't forget to declare the template.

So the **html** should look like this:

```
<!--Defining the controller scope-->
<div ng-controller="carousel">
<!--Declaring the template for later usage-->
<script id="carousel-with-thumbs.html" type="text/ng-template">
<div ng-mouseenter="pause()" ng-mouseleave="play()" class="carousel" ng-swipe-right="prev()"
     ng-swipe-left="next()">
    <div class="carousel-inner" ng-transclude></div>
    <a role="button" href class="left carousel-control" ng-click="prev()"
       ng-class="{ disabled: isPrevDisabled() }"
       ng-show="slides.length > 1">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">previous</span>
    </a>
    <a role="button" href class="right carousel-control" ng-click="next()"
       ng-class="{ disabled: isNextDisabled() }"
       ng-show="slides.length > 1">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">next</span>
    </a>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-show="slides.length > 1">
        <li ng-repeat="slide in slides | orderBy:indexOfSlide track by $index"
            ng-class="{ active: isActive(slide) }" ng-click="select(slide)">
            <!--Showing the thumbnail in a <img> tag -->
            <img ng-src="{{slide.slide.actual.thumb}}">
            <span class="sr-only">slide {{ $index + 1 }} of {{ slides.length }}<span ng-if="isActive(slide)">, currently active</span></span>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
</div>
</script>

<uib-carousel active="active" interval="interval" template-url="carousel-with-thumbs.html">
<uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by $index" index="$index" actual="slide">
    <!--Passing the slide in the actual directive-->
    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>{{slide.title}}</h4>
        <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
    </div>
</uib-slide>
</uib-carousel>
```

Take a moment to analyse the `carousel-indicators` ordered list:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-show="slides.length > 1">
    <li ng-repeat="slide in slides | orderBy:indexOfSlide track by $index" ng-class="{ active: isActive(slide) }"
    ng-click="select(slide)">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.slide.actual.thumb}}">
        <span class="sr-only">slide {{ $index + 1 }} of {{ slides.length }}<span ng-if="isActive(slide)">, currently active</span></span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Look how each `slide` model has another `slide` sub-model which is the transcluded scope of the slide model passed
through the `actual` directive. And then, nested again, the `actual` model containing all the data of each slide:

```
<img ng-src="{{slide.slide.actual.thumb}}">
```

And of course for the big finale, the **controller** should look like this:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
        .controller('carousel', carousel);

        carousel.$inject = ['$scope'];

        function carousel($scope){
            $scope.active = 0;
            $scope.interval = 5000;
            $scope.slides = [
                {title: "Any title", text: "This is a text for the slide", image: "path/to/the/image/image.jpg", thumb:  "path/to/the/image/thumbs/thumb.jpg"},
                {title: "Any title", text: "This is a text for the slide", image: "path/to/the/image/image.jpg", thumb: "path/to/the/image/thumbs/thumb.jpg"},
                {title: "Any title", text: "This is a text for the slide", image: "path/to/the/image/image.jpg", thumb: "path/to/the/image/thumbs/thumb.jpg"}
            ];
    }
})();
```

By the way, I'm using **Angular UI Boostrap 1.3.3** along with **Angular 1.5.8.**

Here's the Fiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/logus/6mvjpf40/

Comment: man please could you get a js fiddle for it i tried it but not working actually

Comment: Ok @HeshamElMasry here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/logus/6mvjpf40/